# Dropdown menu not working in iExplorer?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown menu code, which works great in all browsers except in Explorer. In Explorer, the dropdown menu doesn't function at all. I tried everything in my power to solve this problem but I am not able to. The main horizontal menu is visible and the links seem to work but the dropdown menu that is supposed to appear on hover doesn't appear at all.

Please help!.....

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .nav {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Root Level */
    .dropdown-menu {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: #eeeeee;
    }
    /* Clear the float */
    .dropdown-menu:after {
        display: table;
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }
    .dropdown-menu li {
        display: block;
        border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        min-width: 150px;
        float: left;

    }
    .dropdown-menu li a:link,
    .dropdown-menu li a:visited {
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #111111;
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-menu li a:hover,
    .dropdown-menu li a:focus {
        color: #222222;
    }
    /* Level 1 */
    .dropdown-level-1 {
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        display: none;
        background: grey;
        width: 150px;
    }
    .dropdown-level-1 li {

    }
    /* The ">" triggers the direct child to show up as "block" */
    .dropdown-menu li:hover > .dropdown-level-1 {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Level 2 */
    .dropdown-level-2 {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        background: #888888;
        padding: 0;
        margin: -38px 0 0 148px;
    }
    /* same trick here for level 2 */
    .dropdown-level-1 li:hover > .dropdown-level-2 {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Target all links at once */
    .dropdown-level-0 li a:link,
    .dropdown-level-0 li a:visited,
    .dropdown-level-1 li a:link,
    .dropdown-level-1 li a:visited,
    .dropdown-level-2 li a:link,
    .dropdown-level-2 li a:visited {
        padding: 10px;
        color: purple;
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-level-0 li a:hover,
    .dropdown-level-0 li a:focus,
    .dropdown-level-1 li a:hover,
    .dropdown-level-1 li a:focus,
    .dropdown-level-2 li a:hover,
    .dropdown-level-2 li a:focus {
        color: orange;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-level-1">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-level-1">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-level-1">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-level-1">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2 sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Item 2 sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi your code validates 100% correct, which Explorer are you testing it in?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xqae04yp/ 

Tested in IE and it works just fine for me.